# "invalid command syntax" hg clone ssh windows using .ppk key

Tags: windows, ssh, mercurial, clone, bitbucket

I'm trying to clone a bitbucket repository on a windows platform using an authentication key (.ppk file). I know that the connection to the server is good, as I have had "server refused connection" errors before, but now I am getting an "invalid command syntax error"

This is the command I'm using (I ran the "hg clone" command with the --debug tag to get the full command):

```
running "C:\Program Files/TortoiseHg/lib/tortoiseplink.exe" -ssh -v -i "C:\Users
\user\key.ppk" -noagent hg@bitbucket.org hg@bitbucket.org "hg -R repo/path serve 
--stdio"
```

This is the output I'm getting from this command:

```
running "C:\Program Files/TortoiseHg/lib/tortoiseplink.exe" -ssh -v -i "C:\Users
\user\key.ppk" -noagent hg@bitbucket.org hg@bitbucket.org "hg -R repo/path serve 
--stdio"
sending hello command
sending between command
remote: Looking up host "bitbucket.org"
remote: Connecting to 104.xxx.xxx.1 port 22
remote: Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
remote: Using SSH protocol version 2
remote: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Local:_Feb__4_2012_13:00:34
remote: Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
remote: Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
remote: Host key fingerprint is:
remote: ssh-rsa 2048 97:8c:xx:xx:xx:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
remote: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
remote: Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
remote: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
remote: Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
remote: Reading private key file "C:\Users\user\key.ppk"
remote: Using username "hg".
remote: Offered public key
remote: Remote debug message: Forced command: conq username:user
remote: Remote debug message: Port forwarding disabled.
remote: Remote debug message: X11 forwarding disabled.
remote: Remote debug message: Agent forwarding disabled.
remote: Remote debug message: Pty allocation disabled.
remote: Offer of public key accepted
remote: Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20160523"
remote: Sent public key signature
remote: Remote debug message: Forced command: conq username:user
remote: Remote debug message: Port forwarding disabled.
remote: Remote debug message: X11 forwarding disabled.
remote: Remote debug message: Agent forwarding disabled.
remote: Remote debug message: Pty allocation disabled.
remote: Access granted
remote: Opened channel for session
remote: Started a shell/command
remote: Server sent command exit status 1
remote: Disconnected: All channels closed
remote: conq: invalid command syntax.
hg : abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

If anyone could provide some assistance, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Kenster Sorry about that. I added the text instead of the screenshot as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.

The error was in my call...

the "hg@bitbucket" should have only been in the call once...

```
running "C:\Program Files/TortoiseHg/lib/tortoiseplink.exe" -ssh -v -i "C:\Users
\user\key.ppk" -noagent hg@bitbucket.org "hg -R repo/path serve 
--stdio"
```

I had remapped ssh in the mercurial.ini file as the following:

```
ssh = "C:\Program Files/TortoiseHg/lib/tortoiseplink.exe" -ssh -v -i "C:\Users\user\key.ppk" -noagent hg@bitbucket.org
```

but it should have been:

```
ssh = "C:\Program Files/TortoiseHg/lib/tortoiseplink.exe" -ssh -v -i "C:\Users\user\key.ppk" -noagent
```

Hope this helps someone else having problems ^^

Answer (score 0):

You may also see the lines

```
remote: conq: invalid command syntax.
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

if you have accidentally pasted special characters in your command. This occurred to me having pasted the line

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/your/repo .
```

from within a wiki article. Both the space between `clone` and `ssh` and the period at the end were causing the problem. It is an unfortunate assumption / headache to make and unravel. Type it all by hand is my advice to anyone seeing this error just as a sanity check.